# How to negotiate first salary, when the offer is way lower than the job posting?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, salary, job-offer

I was looking for jobs in data related fields (Data engineering/science), when I found a job opening for software engenieering offering a well above average salary, 2 to 3 times my country's average **That's not common, but I've seen it before**, usually it's from a company from USA/Europe outsorcing their devs.

I decided to apply even though it wasn't exactly what I was looking for (mostly because of the salary), but I can see myself doing it well.

During my first interview they asked me for my salary expectations and **I actually answered the country's average**. I did that for two main reasons:

- Caught by surprise, it was my first job interview (and I wasn't expecting that question).
- The job '*required*' work experience (**which I don't have, and they are aware.**) It intimidated me into asking for such a bigger salary. (Even though it was in the job posting)

The interviewer said it was between their range, asked if it was up for negotiation, I said yes and that was it.

After tests I'm now set for the final interview. I still would rather work in data related field, but I've applied for every opening in the last three months and nothing went foward, so I'm considering taking this job. However if I decide to do so, I belive I'm going to get an offer in the range of my "salary expectation" and not in the range of the job posting.

### **If such an offer is made, is there a way for me to negotiate this, given that the job posting generated some expectations (that I didn't disclose when had the opportunity)? How can I do that?**

Comment: Yes, of course. If they do offer it to you, just say that you've done further research and that you've changed your mind about the salary range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can negotiate it of course - ideally most employment issues would be resolved before the employment contract is signed.

Normally, asking for more at the final interview than you wrote in the initial one is a bit eyebrow raising, but you could ask if your salary could be gradually increased with as you stay with the company and gain experience. That would be nothing out of the ordinary and would be interesting for the employer as well.

But to ensure that the salary increase actually happens, you should make sure the stipulations regarding that are written down clearly and not conditioned with performance but rather by employment duration.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say wait until you get an offer, and when you get an offer, ask here again for advice.

You may have asked for a low number. So what does the company do? They can offer you a very low salary. That risks that you don't take the job, and they have to continue searching. The search costs money, and nobody does the work. Or worse, you take the job, and after six months you decide it isn't enough money and leave. That's worse because you are less effective in *any* job in the first six months, so they get less work than they paid for, and now they have to start all over again.

So there is an excellent chance that the company comes up with a number that makes you happy and that makes you want to stay. Your salary is not that big a part of the entire cost, so better to pay a good salary and have someone working who is motivated to do a good job by a good salary and motivated to stay.

You'll find out when you get the offer.

This question [Is it a good idea to ask for a significantly lower salary than the median to increase the chances of an offer?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44827/is-it-a-good-idea-to-ask-for-a-significantly-lower-salary-than-the-median-to-inc?rq=1) has answers that should be interesting to you.